# Firebase - increase realtime database limit

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app for our school. It contains a score updating feature. i am using firebase database to update the scores. (not published yet) But firebase realtime database offers only 100 RT connections for free.
so is there a way to get more than 100 RT connections for free ? atleast by reducing other features? (like database storage, 5GB media storage..)

Comment: This is a very open-ended question and not very well suited for Stack Overflow. After going over the Firebase documentation, consider taking any questions like this to the firebase-talk forum to generate a discussion. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk

Answer (score 4):

Firebase provides 3 plans.

When you create a project on Firebase, you start with the **Spark Plan**. This plan is free allowing 100 simultaneous connections, 10Gb downloaded per month, 5Gb of Storage and 1Gb for Hosting. This should be good enough for starters.

But if you want more than that, you can pay 25$ per month on the [Flame Plan](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/overview?purchaseBillingPlan=subscription) that gives you unlimited simultaneous connections.

Or go for the [Blaze Plan](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/overview?purchaseBillingPlan=metered) which is Pay as you scale. You get unlimited simultaneous connections, and you'll only pay when your database scales.

And no. You can't get more simultaneous connections by getting rid of other services.

For more information about the plans, you can check the [Pricing Tab on their website](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/).